# Trigonometric integrals in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I'm looking through problems in my complex analysis book, and for some reason I've found a problem I know I could once do, but for some reason I'm stuck on it right now. Here's my work, but I don't know where to go from here.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{3-cos(x)}\\$$

Continue via substitution $z=e^{ix}$
$$dz = iz*dx\ \\ cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{iz\left(3-\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)}$$

$$\frac{-2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2-6z+1} $$

$$\frac{-2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z-z_+)(z-z_-)} $$

One of these is outside the unit circle, so we define that as f(x)

So by Cauchy's theorem, this is equal to...?

My book has a poor explanation of how to use Cauchy's theorem that only leaves me more confused than what I remember. I remember doing something along the lines of $2\pi i *f(x) = $ something, but beyond that I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest version of the Cauchy integral formula is: if $C$ is a simple closed curve, $z_0$ is inside $C$ and $f(z)$ is analytic on and inside $C$, then
$$\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz=2\pi if(z_0)\ .$$
You have (note the typo)
$$\eqalign{-\frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^2-6z+1}
  &=-\frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z-(3+\sqrt8))(z-(3-\sqrt8))}\cr
  &=-\frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)\,dz}{z-z_0}\cr}$$
where $z_0=3-\sqrt8$, which is inside the unit circle, and
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-(3+\sqrt8)}$$
which is analytic everywhere except at $z=3+\sqrt8$, which is outside $C$.  So the integral is
$$-\frac{2}{i}(2\pi i)\frac{1}{(3-\sqrt8)-(3+\sqrt8)}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\ .$$

Comment: AH! I the typo is what caused my error, I was assuming it was my methods that were. Thanks!